# Template inheritance. Fields value overriding

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm using Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 1.

I have a simple template with one field.

[image]

I'm using it to extend eCommerce ConnectSellableItem.

[image]

ConncetSellableItem is extending Commerce Product template.

[image]

An item that based on Commerce Product template has a field with the same name, but different type.

[image]

I'm filling description for my simple template.

[image]

After saving it value replaced with description field value from Content tab.

[image]

Is it intended behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all products,catalogs and categories from Sitecore are not real items, are virtual items which are shown in Content Editor using C**ommerce Engine Connect Catalog Provider**.
The products (products,catalogs, categories) are persistent in **Commerce Engine** not in Sitecore.

To extend sellable item in Sitecore 9.0.1 you need to write C# code, you can not just inherit from another template.

Please have a look on next article where is explained how to extend sellable items for Commerce 9.0.1 : https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/083614

Entity composer functionality was added in Sitecore 9.0.2.

The Entity Composer allows you to build custom data views to contain the properties you want to add to the entity in question. You can then convert this view to a template to be applied to other entities which need the same data to the applied.

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/experience-commerce-entity-composer